# react-virtuoso: overscan props does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtuoso

I'm using `react-virtuoso` library to render a simple virtual list. The code is very straightforward. I pass this `overscan` props and expect the virtual list to render `n` items above and below the viewport but it's not working.

The `ExpensiveComponent`s still renders 'loading...' text when I'm scrolling up and down a little. Here is the code:

```js
import { Virtuoso } from "react-virtuoso";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, PropsWithChildren } from "react";

function ExpensiveComponent({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
  const [render, setRender] = useState(false);
  const mountRef = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    mountRef.current = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (mountRef.current) {
        setRender(true);
      }
    }, 150);

    return () => void (mountRef.current = false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 150, border: "1px solid pink" }}>
      {render ? children : "Loading..."}
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Usage

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Virtuoso
      style={{ height: "400px" }}
      totalCount={200}
      overscan={3} // ----------> this line does not work
      itemContent={(index) => {
        return <ExpensiveComponent>{index}</ExpensiveComponent>;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit 66622199/react-virtuoso-overscan-props-does-not-work]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I missed this detail from the [docs](https://virtuoso.dev/virtuoso-api-reference/). Unlike react-window API, the `overscan` unit is **pixel** instead of **row** in virtual list, in my case I need to increase the `overscan` to `900px` and it seems to be working now.

```js
<Virtuoso
  style={{ height: "400px" }}
  totalCount={200}
  overscan={900}
  itemContent={(index) => {
    return <ExpensiveComponent>{index}</ExpensiveComponent>;
  }}
/>
```